# How can I add an asyncio.sleep?

Tags: python, asynchronous, beautifulsoup, async-await, concurrency

Good afternoon, I am trying to perform an iteration on 50K elements of a page. Apparently, the page has anti-scrape and refuses me the connection at 10K elements or before.
My idea is to add an asyncio.sleep every 1K iterations to avoid the web page blocking but I don't know how to implement it in that **tasks** variable.

GetInfo has as a parameter each url from which different information is extracted.

```py
async def getInfo_async(links: List[str]) -> list:
    res = []
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=48) as executor:
        with requests.Session() as session:
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            tasks = [loop.run_in_executor(executor,getInfo, *(link,session)) for link in links]
            for response in await asyncio.gather(*tasks):
                res.append(response)
    return res
```

I've tried to create a separate asyncio method to add a **sleep** and add it to the **gather**, but I don't know how to do it.
I would have to add the **sleep** in the **tasks variable** where the iterations of the **links** variable containing all the urls to be navigated are performed.

**EDIT 1**

I am trying to use aiohttp as Martijn Pieters has told me, without success so far. The loop does not start

```py
async def main(links):
    tasks = []
    res = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for link in links:
            tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(getInfo(session,link)))
        for response in await asyncio.gather(*tasks):
            res.append(response)
    return res

asyncio.run(main(list1))
```

**EDIT 2**
Does anyone know how to convert my beatifulsoup method with asyncio? I have the following problem:

```
async def getInfo(session,link: str):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        soup = loop.run_in_executor(None, BeautifulSoup, *(link,session))   
       
        data_header_el = soup.find("h1", {"class": "data-header__headline-wrapper"})
        if not data_header_el:
            name = None
        else:
            name = data_header_el.getText().split('\n')[-1].strip()
        noList.append(name)
```

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(tree.content, 'html.parser')  
AttributeError: '_RequestContextManager' object has no attribute 'content'
```

Comment: Why not use a proper rate limiter? I wrote one as an open source package, search for `aiolimiter`.

Comment: I see you are using `requests`. Why not use a URL request library that's asyncio compatible, such as `aiohttp` or `httpx`? Then you don't need to use a threadpool executor.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Because it's a problem I didn't expect to find and I'm just starting out in concurrency, asyncio... This is the only way I know of at the moment, although I will look into it. I will also look at the aiolimiter. I also thought that putting a sleep every n iterations was going to be easy, but I'm having a hard time.

Comment: There are no 'iterations', only code that runs in parallel. Good asyncio code will 'yield' (give up control for other code to run) whenever it would otherwise wait for something to happen. Fetching URLs involves a **lot** of waiting, so is ideal for this kind of cooperation.

Comment: A rate limiter instead keeps track of how often you tried to do something in a given time period, and then yields if a threshold is reached. Like "allow one request every 5 seconds" or "allow 10 requests per second". If the URLs are slow, and you don't try too many in parallel, you could end up never needing to limit the rate.

Comment: @MartijnPieters OK, I've left in the EDIT how I'm doing. I understand that it works like multithreading. Then I'll see how to limit the searches so that it doesn't block me the website.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Your package can be very useful for me to limit the searches in a certain time frame.